# Trying to force Compatibility View to be off for both IE9 and 8.. does 'content="IE-edge" do that for both?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, compatibility

http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"

Will this make Compatibility View be off for both 9 and 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this works for both 8 and 9.